# Why does not the central force $-1/r^4$ violate Bertrand's theorem?

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion

An orbit $r(\theta)$ is said to be bounded if $0<r_{min}\leq r(\theta)\leq r_{max}<\infty$. Otherwise it is called unbounded.

Goldstein defines closed orbits as *orbits in which the particle eventually retraces its own footsteps*.

Bertrand's theorem says that the only forces whose **all bounded orbits are closed** are the inverse-square force and Hook's law.

My concern is the following: The attractive force $-1/r^4$ has **only one bounded orbit**, namely the circular orbit. This can be easily seen by the energy diagram bellow, where it is plotted the effective potential.

[image]

But the circular orbit is certainly closed which seems to violate Bertrand theorem. How to solve this inconsistency?

A possible solution to this paradox would be to consider an alternative definition of open/closed orbits: A bounded orbit is said to be open if, given a sufficiently large time, it completely fills the ring with internal and external radius $r_{min}$ and $r_{max}$. Otherwise it is called closed. Then a circular obit is open since $r_{min}=r_{max}$. It sounds a little weird to say a circular orbit is open though.

Any other explanation? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Bounded essentially means that under a small perturbation, the solution (orbit) remains bounded for all time, clearly your potential only admits a single unstable circular orbit.

Comment: @Triatticus Wouldn't that be the definition of stable orbits instead of the definition of bounded orbits?

Answer (score 8):

An English translation of Bertrand's original work can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2396).  He opens by quoting the [Binet equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation), but this implicitly rules out circular orbits from everything that follows.

As a result, his proof holds only in the case of non-circular orbits.  If your potential does not admit non-circular bounded orbits, then Bertrand's theorem does not apply.  This is equivalent to the requirement that the potential admits **stable** bounded orbits.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an object with energy $E$, as seen in the graph below:

[image]

The line of constant $E$ intersects $V_\text{eff}(r)$ at two radii, $r_1$ and $r_2$. These are the boundaries of two separate regions where motion is possible: $r \leqslant r_1$ and $r \geqslant r_2$ (solid red lines).

Let's only consider motion in the region $r \leqslant r_1$. At radius $r_1$, we have $\dot{r} = 0$ and $\ddot{r} \sim -V'_\text{eff}(r_1) < 0$, so it is a turning point of maximum radius. Since there is no corresponding turning point of minimum radius, this means that once $\dot{r} < 0$, the object will spiral towards the center, forever.

Therefore, the orbit of this object is bound by $r_1$, but it is not closed.

Comment: I agree that the orbit with energy E and $r\leq r_1$ is not closed. But can I call this a limited orbit according to my first definition? Note that it requires two finite, non zero turning points. If I change that definition then the problem is solved.

Comment: @Diracology A bounded orbit is an orbit for which $r_\max$ is finite. It's perfectly fine for $r_\min = 0$, in fact all radial orbits (i.e. orbits with zero angular momentum) in attracting central force fields have that property.

Answer (score 1):

You have written it: Bertrand's theorem is concerned with central forces for which **all** bounded orbits are closed, i.e. either the initial conditions are such that the mass goes to infinity, or it they are such that the trajectory is a close orbit. Whether there exists **some** close orbits is irrelevant to Bertrand's theorem.

Comment: But in my example there is only one bounded orbit and it is closed by Goldstein's definition. Hence all bounded orbits associated with that force is closed.

Comment: ah, ok, I see your point. But from the top of my memory, there are orbits spiralling in with $1/r^4$. So I think your statement that there is only one bounded orbit is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Bertrand Theorem is actually applicable for bounded orbits which are also stable. The potential $-1/r^4$ do allow a circular orbit, but that is unstable. For any force law of the form $f=-kr^n$, stable orbits are only possible for $n>-3$.

The force law (equation 3.48 of Goldstein) $$f(r)=-\frac{k}{r^{3-\beta ^2}}$$ corresponds to stable bounded orbits only for $\beta ^2=1$ and $\beta ^2=4$. Also follow the discussion after equation 3.48 of Goldstein where this is explained in details.